# Suggested edit ban modal in Mod Dashboard tab shows templating variable instead of username

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, profile-page, moderator-tools

In the Mod Dashboard, the modal dialogue that pops up to ask how long to make a suggested edit ban has a minor bug. The text of this modal has what looks like a template bug where it fails to populate the username:

[image: Dialogue box asking “How many days do you want to ban @(Model.DisplayName) from suggesting edits?”]

This bug only shows up in the Mod Dashboard tab, when using the tab's own link. The top banner that is added to all profile tabs for a user with current issues (e.g. has a question block) *also* has a suggested edit ban link, but that one appears to be populating the username correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some JavaScript code was moved from a server side file (actually, an ASP.NET/MVC view file) to a JavaScript file, and the developer who moved the code did not notice the server side code.

I've updated the files and code to work correctly, with you in the next build.